Movie about ability to touch objects and know its past
I'm trying to find an American(?) movie I saw a long time ago about a man who has a supernatural ability to touch any object and instantly be able to know its past, where it's been, etc. I recall one part where someone sets something, I think a coin, in his hand and he says that it was once in the possession of Queen Elizabeth, or something along those lines. It was based in a city, such as New York. I thought it was Nicolas Cage, but I just went through the details of every Nicolas Cage movie twice, and cannot find it. I believe the genre was a suspense thriller and/or detective movie. It was definitely more than 10, maybe even 15 years ago that I saw it.
What movie is this?
